# How to make a fake socket object from file or string in python?

Tags: python, sockets, procedure, pypy

I try to use pypy 2.5.1 replace python 2.7:

I used mechanize 0.2.5 package for pypy：

The problem is on /mechanize/_ulib2_fork.py line 70

```
try:
    socket._fileobject("fake socket", close=True)
except TypeError:
    ....
```

here I want to replace the "fake socket" string with some real fake socket.
How to do it?

I want to do this because:

the _fileobject function will invoke **init** function and the **init()**:

```
 def __init__(self, sock, mode='rb', bufsize=1, close=False):
     socket._resue()  //there will be error
```

the _reuse() function only defined in socket object not string object

(Actually, for combine with mechanize and pypy, I get AttributeError replace NameEorror. The reason is the socket would be string 'str' replace the reality socket object here. I need a presudo socket object here)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the source](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py), this is a hack done only to check if we're running a very old version of Python (<= 2.4).  You can fix it by completely deleting it (so in the link above, delete lines 69-74 and de-indent the following lines 75-76).

Comment: for combine with mechanize and pypy, I get AttributeError replace NameEorror. The reason is the socket would be string 'str' replace the reality socket object here.

Comment: the link provided is down, mechanize project was moved to other project, so the correct link is https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py